# Facebook API : Cannot register an achievement with facebook

Tags: php, facebook

I spent a lot of time trying to register an achievement with facebook using grahp API, but 
I am always getting this :

`{"error":{"type":"OAuthException","message":"(#2) Object at achievement URL is not of type game.achievement"}}`

The code is :

```
$achievementUrl = 'http://www.dappergames.com/test.html';
$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' . $appID . '/achievements?achievement=' . 
        $achievementUrl . '&display_order=' . $order . '&access_token=' . $accessToken . '';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
print_r($data);
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Go to your application settings in facebook as admin and check whether you have categorized your application under games category... I think that would solve your problem.

Comment: Hey Vijay, my app is categorized as "Games" app. So this should not be a reason.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at [your test](http://www.dappergames.com/test.html), you're missing the most important tag, og:url.

Facebook uses that tag to find the location of where to parse the information, I was having a similar problem on adding achievements to my app until I figured that out. Here's how mine looks. Mine passes the [debugger](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) and works currently on Facebook.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
   <title>Game Loader</title>
   <meta property="og:type" content="game.achievement"/>
   <meta property="og:title" content="Game Loader"/>
   <meta property="og:url" content="FULL LINK TO THIS PAGE"/>
   <meta property="og:description" content="You loaded the gam!e"/>
   <meta property="og:image" content="Link to 50x50 image"/>
   <meta property="og:points" content="10"/>
   <meta property="fb:app_id" content="YOUR_APP_ID"/>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

After updating your HTML to this, run it through the debugger linked above so that it is updated on Facebook's end (and to see if you receive any warnings) and then create it and give it to users.

Here's how I created it:

```
curl -D "achievement=[URL TO ACHIEVEMENT]&access_token=[APPLICATION ACCESS TOKEN]" https://graph.facebook.com/APP_ID/achievements
```

and I then rewarded it to users using the Facebook Javascript API on my canvas application like so:

```
FB.api('/'+user_id+'/achievements', 'POST', { 'access_token': [APPLICATION ACCESS TOKEN], 'achievement':[FULL URL]},
        function(response) {
                if(console)
                        console.log(response);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have the correct Open Graph meta tags in your achievement URL `$achievementUrl`:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#">
  <head>
    <title>ACHIEVEMENT_TITLE</title>
    <meta property="og:type" content="game.achievement"/>
    <meta property="og:url" content="URL_FOR_THIS_PAGE"/>
    <meta property="og:title" content="ACHIEVEMENT_TITLE"/>
    <meta property="og:description" content="ACHIEVEMENT_DESCRIPTON"/>
    <meta property="og:image" content="URL_FOR_ACHIEVEMENT_IMAGE"/>
    <meta property="og:points" content="POINTS_FOR_ACHIEVEMENT"/>
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="YOUR_APP_ID"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    Promotional content for the Achievement.  
    This is the landing page where a user will be directed after
    clicking on the achievement story.
  </body>
</html>
```

The above is just an example from this [post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/539/). Note the first meta tag in the example? I suppose it's missing in your page.

Comment: thanks for your help, but I got the same meta code on my test achievement url - http://www.dappergames.com/test.html. It looks the same as your example, but with filled in values.

Comment: @Dantenello: are you blocking the Facebook robots? running your url on the [Facebook debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dappergames.com%2Ftest.html) is giving page couldn't be reached!

Comment: @ifaour the page could not be reached error because the test page is missing the og:url parameter, in opengraph that attribute is used as a permanent link and is the one the debugger retrieves information from.

Comment: @kasra, I guess the page have been edited, the one in the comments above was containing all the open graph meta tags. Also my answer contains the `og:url` tag, no need for cross-answering

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Game Loader"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="FULL LINK TO THIS PAGE"/>
```

These are required fields. Provide all the required fields and try again with the debugger tool, if debugger tool passes your page then you are ok to register achievement.